# Program doesn't run, too much work?

Tags: c++

When I run this, it just opens up the command prompt window with only the underscore blinking at the start. I waited 20 minutes, nothing happened, there's no text/error.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int prime(unsigned __int64 para) {          // returns 1 if para is a prime number
    for (unsigned __int64 i = 2; i < para; i++) {
        if (para % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;  
}

int main()
{
    for (unsigned __int64 i = 300851475143; i > 2; i--) {
        if (prime(i) == true) {                  //  checks if i is prime
            if (600851475143 % i == 0) {         //  checks if 600851475143 is divisible by said prime, print it if so
                cout << i << endl;
                break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just try some smaller numbers? What else have you tried?

Comment: You need to debug your code on your own. Try to find out where's the problem... you can't just post your program here and write that it doesn't work. Read FAQ and About page.

Comment: This is an extremely inefficient way of determining if a number is a prime...

Comment: I ran this and my machine cried digital tears.

Comment: Let us assume for a moment that the body of the loop in main takes one microsecond to execute. A very optimistic assumption, but let's roll with it. It will then take 300851475142 microseconds to execute all iterations, right? That's over 3 days.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem. It's not perfect, but it doesn't cook processors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complexity of the program is huge - it would take forever to run. It is possibly valid, but the number of iterations in `for` loops is just enormous.

You are trying to run this loop:

```
for (unsigned __int64 i = 300851475143; i > 2; i--)
```

which alone is way too big for the program to finish quickly.

In addition to that, in `prime()` you're running a second loop:

```
for (unsigned __int64 i = 2; i < para; i++)
```

which (since `para` is related to `i` in the outer loop) makes the complexity O(n^2)

Answer (score 2):

You know `300851475143` is a huge number and you have two nested loops which work around this number !

If each iteration takes `1ns` you need `300s x 300s = 25 hours` to finish the job. *(It's just an approximation)*

Comment: More like 150,000 years (`3e11^2 * 1ns / 2`). :)